# How can I ensure correct drawing order in an OverlayLayout?

Tags: java, swing, repaint, jmapviewer

I am using a `JPanel` with an `OverlayLayout` to draw two unrelated components on top of each other. Specifically, I have a transparent component which contains my own line drawings, and beneath that, I am using a `JMapViewer` component, which displays OpenStreetMap tiles. This works.

Except when the JMapViewer loads tiles asynchronously. In that case, it calls `repaint()` on itself when the loading is finished, and it draws itself over my line layer. My line layer cannot know this, since it cannot know when the JMapViewer chooses to repaint itself.

Now I would have expected the `JPanel` to repaint my line layer when the map layer repaints, since it knows the correct drawing order and knows that my line layer has to be repainted. But it doesn't do this.

How would you solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JMapViewer`](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JMapViewer) implements `TileLoaderListener` and simply calls `repaint()` when loading is finished. You should be able to update the map and then forward the event to your layer, as suggested below.

```
MyViewer map = new MyViewer();
...
private class MyViewer extends JMapViewer {

    @Override
    public void tileLoadingFinished(Tile tile, boolean success) {
        super.tileLoadingFinished(tile, success);
        lineLayer.repaint(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> it calls repaint() on itself when the loading is finished,

Call repaint() on the parent panel instead.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how the `JMapViewer` repaints itself. If it just updates its content, the parent(s) might not even notice that something has changed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best approach, but it's the only one I can think of.  You could replace the RepaintManager for the JMapComponent with a custom one that also manages repaints of your overlayed component.  That way, you can guarantee that your overlayed component always gets repainted last.

...do this from the AWT event thread via SwingUtilities

```
RepaintManager myManager = new RepaintManager() {
   public void  addDirtyRegion(JComponent c, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
....implemnt code here to guarentee your top level component gets repainted whenever 'c' is the JMapComponent
   }
}

RepaintManager.setCurrentManager(myManager);
```

Comment: Thank you. I am dealing with *another* map viewer component now, for which trashgod's approach does not work (because it does not have a hook for listeners), but yours does.