# Displaying location on a world map

Tags: java, swing, google-maps, jxmapviewer

I am working on a Java desktop application. In this project I want to highlight some location on a world map. These locations are stored in a database. I have found a link to [Building Maps into Your Swing Application with the JXMapViewer](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/10/30/building-maps-into-swing-app-with-jxmapviewer.html),
but I'm still not finding the proper way to do this. Can anyone can give me some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

for me google works http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/10/30/building-maps-into-swing-app-with-jxmapviewer.html any google related question(s)

Comment: Not your down-voter, but they may have overlooked your corrected link. +1

Comment: thanks for your response....ok i will try with this code then will ask if i face any problem with it

Comment: There is some error in this code with getInstance() method and i am unable to resolve this as i dont know about JXmapviewer.And i am also unable to find other example code for JXMapViewer.If u know some link which ca help me or other idea please guide me......

Comment: that's so academic discusion, long time that I tried this one, I hope that still there are bundled examples packed (if you download that and inport to to IDE) in code source

Answer (score 2):

If you are building swt app, you can use [SWT Browser widget](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-browser-widget/browser.html) with Google Maps API. All you need is to generate simple html page and show it with the use of SWT Browser

Comment: actually this application is not based on SWT just using swing

Answer (score 2):

You might like to look at [`JMapViewer`](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JMapViewer), recently mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831152).

Addendum: For example,

```
svn co http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/viewer/jmapviewer jmapviewer
ant
java -cp bin org.openstreetmap.gui.jmapviewer.Demo
```

Comment: The last line in your instructions doesnt work, but JMapViewer is really good.