# What are some lightweight map toolkits?

Tags: java, dictionary

I am looking into building an application in Java that requires a very light weight interactive map.  Worldwind is definitely too heavy for this application, I'm leaning towards openmap but what other well supported alternatives are there?  I'd prefer something even more light weight than openmap.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying location on a world map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841747/displaying-location-on-a-world-map)

Comment: I disagree, the other question doesn't specify the lightweight requirement.

Comment: It may help to clarify the definition of "lightweight" in this context.

Answer (score 1):

[`JMapViewer`](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JMapViewer) works as advertised. See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841747/displaying-location-on-a-world-map/5843361#5843361).

Comment: can you post more information such as what are the processing requirements, how light weight is that package?  And is there any detailed documentation?

Comment: I see ~3096 KiB, but you'll need to judge for yourself.